# Метод в Python, выводящий все экземпляры своего класса

Tags: python, ооп

Как создать метод в Python, который будет выводить все экземпляры того же класса, в котором определен этот метод?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос в английской версии SO ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328882/5741205)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот вариант в котором не течет память, и который поддерживает оборачивание нескольких классов.

Метакласс:

```
import weakref


class MyMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instances = {}
        super(MyMeta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_instances(self):
        return list(self.__instances.values())

    def delete(self, id_instance):
        del self.__instances[id_instance]

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(MyMeta, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__instances[id(instance)] = weakref.proxy(instance)
        return instance
```

Использование (можно создать несколько таких классов, не копируя метакласс):

```
class MyClass(object, metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __del__(self):
        # этот метод и действие внутри него обязательно, иначе будет течь память под прокси
        self.__class__.delete(id(self))


print(MyClass.get_instances())
a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
print(MyClass.get_instances())
del b
print(MyClass.get_instances())
```

Answer (score 6):

Взял пример синглтона через мета-класс, немного его изменил и получился такой вот пример.

**Эта реализация будет собирать экземпляры для всех классов с данным мета-классом**

```
class MyMeta(type):
    instances = []

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(MyMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.instances.append(instance)

        return instance


# Python2
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta


# Python3
class MyClass(object, metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass


print(MyClass.instances)

a = MyClass()
print(MyClass.instances)

b = MyClass()
c = MyClass()
print(MyClass.instances)
```

Консоль:

```
[]
[<__main__.MyClass object at 0x00514AF0>]
[<__main__.MyClass object at 0x00514AF0>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0x00736DF0>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0x00736C30>]
```

Comment: Правильней будет определять instances в MyMeta.__init__ , так можно будет корректно использовать метакласс для нескольких классов

Comment: @AndrioSkur, как насчет вам привести в ответ свой улучшенный пример? :)

Comment: Ох память будет течь)

Comment: @andreymal, будет! :D

Comment: @gil9red добавил.

Comment: @andreymal а у меня не будет))

Comment: @AndrioSkur, +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

```
instances = []

def decor(cls):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        instances.append(obj)
        return obj
    return wrap

@decor
class A: pass

print(instances)  # []
A()
print(instances)  # [<__main__.A object at 0x02D10C10>]
A()
print(instances)  # [<__main__.A object at 0x02D10C10>, <__main__.A object at 0x02D10F50>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы это имели в виду?

```
class A:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        A.count += 1

    def get_count(self):
        return self.count

a = A()
a.count
>> 1
a.get_count()
>> 1
b = A()
a.count
>> 2
b.get_count()
>> 2
```

Comment: Автор хотел таки не количество их, а сами экземпляры ) Думаю тут без метакласса не обойтись, Его пример для синглетора в питоне можно увидеть, а если изменить немного, то и собирать через него экземпляры