# Можно ли получить все существующие объекты класса через класс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

У меня есть класс *Cluster* и несколько его экземпляров. В каждом экземпляре класса *Cluster* есть поле *elements*, которое представляет собой список координат элементов кластера.

Я хочу описать статический метод, который бы получал координаты элемента и возвращал объект кластера, к которому он относится, а для этого мне нужно получить доступ ко всем созданным над данный момент объектам класса.

Вопрос: как это сделать?

Вот упрощенный код класса кластера:

```
class Cluster:

    def __init__(self, x, y, label):
        self.elements = []          # Список координат элементов кластера

    # Метод добавления элемента в кластер
    def add_element(self, x, y):
        self.elements.append((x, y))

    # Метод проверки наличия элемента в кластере
    def have_element(self, x, y):
        return (x, y) in self.elements

    # Метод поиска кластера элемента
    @staticmethod
    def find_element_cluster(x, y):
        pass
        # Что тут надо писать?
```

А вот результат, которого я хочу добиться:

```
element = 4, 6
cluster = Cluster.find_element_cluster(element[0], element[1])
# Теперь в переменной cluster хранится объект кластера, который имеет элемент element
```

Comment: XY-задача если вы хотите искать cluster по х, y  так и поддерживайте явно словарь (или R-tree или какая структура больше подходит в вашем случае) `(x, y)-> cluster` https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044

Comment: нашел связанный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684961/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-python-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import weakref


class KeepRefs(object):
    __refs__ = defaultdict(list)

    def __init__(self):
        self.__refs__[self.__class__].append(weakref.ref(self))

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        for inst_ref in cls.__refs__[cls]:
            inst = inst_ref()
            if inst is not None:
                yield inst


class Cluster(KeepRefs):
    ...


a = Cluster(...)
b = Cluster(...)
c = Cluster(...)

instances = list(Cluster.get_instances())
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328882/1911548)